# Windows Embedded Developer Update (Embedded Compact 7)

Tags: windows-embedded-compact

I have been trying to get the WEDU tool to work for Embedded Compact 7 and I'm having no luck.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4cba2503-eb2a-410b-8429-5c63e226dad8/where-to-find-windows-embedded-ce-70-updates?forum=winembnatapp

Looking at this form, I've followed the instructions.  When I get to the registration part, the form comes up and I click Continue, but it never gets me registered.  I'm sent to a page with a whole bunch of download links.  Has Microsoft broken this registration process?

Answer (score 0):

It used to be that if you didn't agree to the question

> Do you agree that a Windows Embedded representative may contact you using the phone number or email address provided by you to supply further Windows Embedded Information

then [registration would fail](https://guruce.com/blogpost/wedu-endless-loop-in-registration-pages-problem-solved), and you would be sent back to the initial page.